# IPv6 firewall rules seem to impede all connections

Tags: iptables, ipv6

After deciding that my small server needed a firewall, I used ferm to configure iptables and ip6tables for me (this question should be tagged ferm, but I cannot create the tag).

I am using the same rules for both ipv4 and ipv6, but as soon as I put up the firewall, IPv6 connections (on all ports) stop working and I have to drop to IPv4. Why could that be?

My /etc/ferm.conf

```
domain (ip ip6) table filter {
    chain INPUT {
        policy DROP;

        # connection tracking
        mod state state INVALID DROP;
        mod state state (ESTABLISHED RELATED) ACCEPT;

        # allow local connections
        interface lo ACCEPT;

        # respond to ping
        proto icmp icmp-type echo-request ACCEPT;

        # allow SSH connections
        proto tcp dport ssh ACCEPT;

        # allow all my lovely server stuff
        proto tcp dport (http https smtp imap imaps) ACCEPT;

        # Teamspeak 3 Server
        proto tcp dport (10011 30033) ACCEPT;
        proto udp dport 9987 ACCEPT;

        # Prosody XMPP
        proto tcp dport (5222 5269) ACCEPT;

        # ident connections are also allowed
        proto tcp dport auth ACCEPT;

        # the rest is dropped by the above policy
    }

    # outgoing connections are not limited
    chain OUTPUT policy ACCEPT;

    # this is not a router
    chain FORWARD policy DROP;
}
```

ip6tables -vnL

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 DROP       all      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 state INVALID
   24  8224 ACCEPT     all      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    0     0 ACCEPT     all      lo     *       ::/0                 ::/0
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmpv6    *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 ipv6-icmptype 128
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 tcp dpt:22
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 tcp dpt:80
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 tcp dpt:443
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 tcp dpt:25
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 tcp dpt:143
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 tcp dpt:993
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 tcp dpt:10011
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 tcp dpt:30033
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 udp dpt:9987
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 tcp dpt:5222
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 tcp dpt:5269
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 tcp dpt:113

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 24 packets, 8224 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that you are dropping most ICMPv6 packets. Many essential IPv6 functions depend on ICMPv6, such as Neighbor Discovery (equivalent to ARP in IPv4). ICMP is a crucial part of the IP protocols (both IPv4 and IPv6) but the impact of bad ICMP filtering is much more severe for IPv6 than for IPv4. You are probably better off by allowing all ICMP and then (maybe) filter out things that you don't want.

For more background information take a look at [RFC 4890](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4890).